# Is there a way to rotate the camera's image at the driver level, not processing graphics after capture?

Tags: camera, pi-4, touchscreen

I've mounted an Arducam 5 MP camera inside a SmartiPi 2 case with the official 7" touchscreen powered by a Pi 4. Unfortunately, when I take a picture or use it as a webcam, the camera appears to be rotated 90˚ to the right. Is there a way to rotate the image at the driver level, or another way to make the image be right-side-up? The primary intention is to use it as a video conferencing device, so post-processing isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same setup and same problem.
I got my case from Adafruit and the setup instructions at smarticase.com/setup says to do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

then add this right above `exit 0`

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=rotate=90
```

It **works**!  What I was missing was the fact that I thought the "412" was a number, when in fact it is the number 4, the lower case letter l, and the number 2! Once I put that in rc.local, all is well.

Comment: OK, it works. But although you should take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. It is possible that it suddenly doesn't run anymore after an upgrade.

Comment: I forgot about this question! This is the same solution I came up with, but it put it in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: What then is the solution to rotate the screen 90 degrees to the right?